# figure captions - the way to describe

Tags: prepositions, word-order, clauses, headlinese

When I am describing a ***figure caption*** in a technical paper, I think it should be concise.
So what should I say if I am describing *a poly line whose irregularities are preserved by the technique that we adopted*.
So, if I write:

> 1. A poly line edge **having** preserved major irregularities
> 2. A poly line edge **with** preserved major irregularities

What would be most appropriate?

Comment: I'd say that they are equally appropriate

Comment: I think you could also move *preserved* to the end.

Comment: @snailboat: that mean => A poly line edge "having" major irregularities "preserved"

Comment: I'd prefer “with” or “that has”. “Having” sounds incorrect, probably due to tense mismatch with “preserved” (present progressive vs. simple past).

Comment: I'm aware that “preserved” is functioning as an adjective here, but if you'll forgive my non-technical description I think my point still stands.

Comment: Technique to preserve poly line irregularities

Comment: @Tyler James Young: sound good. that mean,  A poly line edge "that has (or with)" major irregularities "preserved"

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatically correct.

However, when reading (and writing) technical papers, I am a big proponent of clear and concise wording.  #2 sounds better, with Tyler James Young's suggestion of moving "preserved" to the end:

> A poly line edge with major irregularities preserved.

Why use two syllables (having) when you can use one (with)?  This says exactly what you need to say with no syllables wasted.